# Casting Parent Class to Child Class in Single Table per Class Hierarchy

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm trying to set up a user case, where I have one generic form that can handle all types of `UploadedFile` user uploads.  So, here is my setup:

```
@Entity(name="UploadedForm")
@Table(name="uploaded_file")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class UploadedFile implements Serializable{

    /** 
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6810328674369487649L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    protected String name = null;

    @Column(name="bytes",unique=true)
    @Lob
    protected byte[] bytes;

    @Column(name="type",nullable=false, updatable=false, insertable=false)
    protected String type;


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    protected User user;

    @Column(name="date_submitted")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    protected Date dateSubmitted;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public Date getDateSubmitted() {
        return dateSubmitted;
    }
    public void setDateSubmitted(Date dateSubmitted) {
        this.dateSubmitted = dateSubmitted;
    }

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void populateDateSubmitted(){
        this.dateSubmitted = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
    }
    public byte[] getBytes() {
        return bytes;
    }
    public void setBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        this.bytes = bytes;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

}


@Entity(name="Document")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="Document")
public class DocumentFile extends UploadedFile {

    public void setDateSubmitted(Date dateSubmitted) {
        this.dateSubmitted = dateSubmitted;
    }

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void populateDateSubmitted(){
        this.dateSubmitted = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
    }
    public byte[] getBytes() {
        return bytes;
    }
    public void setBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        this.bytes = bytes;
    }
}


@RequestMapping( value="{type}",method=RequestMethod.GET )
    public String showForm(ModelMap model, @PathVariable("type") String type){
        UploadedFile form = null;
        if((model.get("FORM") == null)){
            if(type.equals("document")){
                form =  new DocumentFile();
            }
            else if( type.equals("image")){
                form =  new ImageFile();
            }
        }else{
            form = (UploadedFile)model.get("FORM");
            if(form.getClass() == DocumentFile.class)
                form = (DocumentFile)form;
            else if(form.getClass() == ImageFile.class)
                form = (ImageFile)form;
        }


        model.addAttribute("message", "Please select your file and hit submit.");

        model.addAttribute("FORM", form);

        model.addAttribute("type", type);

        return "upload_form";
    }
    @RequestMapping( method=RequestMethod.POST )
    public String processForm(Model model, @RequestParam(value="type") String type, @ModelAttribute(value="FORM") UploadedFile form,BindingResult result, Principal principal) throws FileSaveException, Exception{
        if(!result.hasErrors()){

            UploadedFile savedFile = null;

            try {
                // Find the currently logged in user.  There has to be a more eloquent way...
                String username = principal.getName();
                User user = uService.findByName(username);

                // Set the associated user to the UploadedFile
                form.setUser(user);

                if(type.equals("document"))
                    form = (DocumentFile)form;
                else if(type.equals("image"))
                    form = (ImageFile)form;

                // Persist the file
                savedFile = this.saveFile(form);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                FileSaveException fse =  new FileSaveException("Unable to save file: " + e.getMessage());

                fse.setStackTrace(e.getStackTrace());

                throw fse;

            }
            model.addAttribute("message", "SUCCESS!");
            model.addAttribute("FORM", savedFile);
            return "upload_success";

        }else{

            return "upload_form";

        }
    }
```

---

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/includes.jsp" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/header.jsp" %>
<head>
<title>upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Upload Stuff -</h1>
    ${message}
    <br />
    <br />

    <form:form commandName="FORM" action="/upload"
        enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="${ type }"/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="color: red;"><form:errors path="*"
                        cssStyle="color : red;" /> ${errors}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name :</td>
                <td>
                    <form:input type="text" path="name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>File:</td>
                <td>
                    <form:input type="file" path="bytes" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
    <br />
    <a href="/">Go home</a>
</body>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/footer.jsp"%>
```

And the error I'm getting is:

> Unable to cast Object `UploadedFile` to `DocumentFile`

Any idea why?

**UPDATE:**  I found a workaround by not passing around the UploadedFile, instead passing the Concrete class I actually want to persist.  I also had to remove the controller/service/dao methods and create one for each UploadedFile child.  Seems like there should be a better way to do this.  Please give your suggestions.  Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem looks to be more about Spring than Hibernate. This:

```
@ModelAttribute(value="FORM") UploadedFile form
```

Spring has no way of knowing, when it translates the incoming request, that you want it to create a `DocumentFile` instaead of an `UploadedFile`. It may be possible to create your own `ConversionService`, but it's probably easier just to have different request-mappings for your different forms. Like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/post/uploadedfile", method=RequestMethod.POST )
public String processUploadedFileForm(Model model, @RequestParam(value="type") String type, @ModelAttribute(value="FORM") UploadedFile form,BindingResult result, Principal principal) throws FileSaveException, Exception{
...
}

@RequestMapping(value="/post/documentfile", method=RequestMethod.POST )
public String processDocumentFileForm(Model model, @RequestParam(value="type") String type, @ModelAttribute(value="FORM") DocumentFile form,BindingResult result, Principal principal) throws FileSaveException, Exception{
...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing.  I posted that in my update message.  Was just hoping there was a cleaner way of doing it.  Thank you so much for your suggestion. :)

Comment: "Spring has no way of knowing, when it translates the incoming request, that you want it to create a <child> instaead of an <parent>." This statement confuses me, because if I send a "child" object to the form, and reflection is used to populate form fields, I expect the framework to understand, or "remember," to send a "child" object back, via a respective POST method in the controller.

Comment: @Rick then I'm afraid you will be disappointed with Spring MVC. It's different from ASP or JSF, it doesn't maintain complex view-state and the view is loosely coupled with the model. If you're looking for that level of "intelligence", then Spring is not right for you. On the other hand, you'll find that more complex and tightly coupled frameworks tie your hands in many other ways instead, so there's always a trade-off :)

Comment: @pap you are correct.  I was a little ignorant about the wisdom of not maintaining state between view renders.  I think Spring MVC is indeed for me.  :)  In this way, I think Spring MVC makes the implementation more maintainable and easier to understand.  I created parent/child controllers to manage the view's parent/child "command" models.  But my implementation and confusion are beyond the scope of this post. :)